# numpy ndarray dtype convertion failed

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, writetofile, dtype

I have a piece of code that did some ndarray transformation, and I'd like to convert the final output to be np.int8 type and output it to file. However, the conversion did not work. Here is the piece of code:

```
print("origin dtype:", image[0].dtype)
print(type(image[0]))
image[0] = image[0].astype(np.uint8)
print(image[0])
print("image datatype1：",image[0].dtype)
image[0].tofile(f'{image_name}_{org_h}_{org_w}_{dst_h}_{dst_w}.bin')
print("image datatype2：",image[0].dtype)
```

Here is what I got:

```
origin dtype: float32
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[[ 71.  73.  73. ... 167. 170. 173.]
  [ 62.  63.  64. ... 164. 168. 170.]
  [ 54.  56.  57. ... 157. 163. 165.]
  ...
 [142. 154. 138. ... 115.  91. 111.]
  [158. 127. 123. ... 128. 130. 113.]
  [133. 114. 106. ... 114. 110. 106.]]]
image datatype1： float32
image datatype2： float32
```

Can somebody help me with where it went wrong?

Comment: What is `image`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rows of a 2D array cannot have a different dtypes: when you assign a `uint8` array to the row of a `float32` array, it is cast to `float32`; for example:

```python
image = np.ones((4, 4), dtype='float32')
print(image[0].dtype)
# float32

image[0] = image[0].astype('uint8')
print(image[0].dtype)
# float32
```

Your options are either to convert the dtype of the entire array at once:

```python
image = image.astype('uint8')
print(image[0].dtype)
# uint8
```

Or to convert your 2D array to a list of 1D arrays, each of which can then have its own dtype:

```
image = list(image)
print(image[0].dtype)
# float32

image[0] = image[0].astype('uint8')
print(image[0].dtype)
# uint8
```